# Can I write this Gaussian quadratic in an alternate way

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of dependent variables termed $y$ which are observed as multidimensional vectors and I have similar independent variables $x$ which are of the same dimension. They are related by a linear transformation, which we will denote by $A$. So, $y_i = Ax_i + \epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i$ is the noise for the ith observation.

The noise is also modeled with a Gaussian distribution and is independent for each of the observations but not identical. So, I can write the distribution for the observations as:

$$
P(Y|X) \propto \prod_{i=1}^{N}\exp \big((y_i - Ax_i)^T w_i I (y_i - Ax_i)\big)
$$

where $w_i I$ is the Identity matrix scaled by the noise variance at each point.

My question is whether I can simplify this as:

$$
P(Y|X) \propto \prod_{i=1}^{N}\exp \big(w_i(y_i - Ax_i)^T (y_i - Ax_i)\big)
$$

I notice that $(y_i - Ax_i)^T (y_i - Ax_i)$ is a scalar and this makes sense to me but I wanted to verify as I am always second-guessing myself on such things.